# Ambiguous implicits with virtual types and Numeric

Tags: scala, types

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.2 (Java HotSpot 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_15).

scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

trait Reduce { type X; def add(x:X) }
```

I now declare a class, `Foo`, which can fill from a `Reducer`, or `chain` with one.

```
class Foo[A](val a:A) {
  def fill(r: Reduce { type X = A}) = {r.add(a)}
  def chain[R >:A](r: Reduce { type X = R }) = { r.add(a); new Foo(r)}
}
```

I now create a class which is a reducer for some numerical type `Y`

```
class AsInt[Y: Numeric] extends Reduce { 
  type X = Y
  var i = 0
  override def add(y:Y) = {i = implicitly[Numeric[Y]].toInt(y)}
}
```

And I'm done

```
// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined trait Reduce
defined class Foo
defined class AsInt
```

I can now create and fill an instance of `Foo`:

```
scala> val fL = new Foo(123L)
fL: Foo[Long] = Foo@12979ef0

scala> fL.fill(new AsInt)
```

So far so good. Now I chain one:

```
scala> fL.chain(new AsInt)
<console>:12: error: ambiguous implicit values:
 both object BigIntIsIntegral in object Numeric of type scala.math.Numeric.BigIntIsIntegral.type
 and object IntIsIntegral in object Numeric of type scala.math.Numeric.IntIsIntegral.type
 match expected type Numeric[Y]
              fL.chain(new AsInt)
                       ^
```

Now I'm stuck. The typer should be looking for some type `R >: Long`, for which there is an implicit `Numeric[R]` in scope. How can either a `Numeric[Int]` or a `Numeric[BigInt]` possibly fit the bill?

The typer seems to have no problems with solving it:

```
scala> def foo[Z >: Long](implicit N: Numeric[Z]) = println(N)
foo: [Z >: Long](implicit N: Numeric[Z])Unit

scala> foo
scala.math.Numeric$LongIsIntegral$@67236f24
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I've run into a similar problem in the past and my conclusion was that the compiler just wasn't going to take the constraints on an aliased type into consideration (no idea why). Here's a [reduced example](https://gist.github.com/travisbrown/6423914).

Comment: Yeah, same here. Error messages from scalac for implicits are often misleading.

Comment: Also, have you tried compiling with: -Xlog-implicits

Comment: from what I understand, but I might be mistaken, `Z :> Long` will look for a common type in the hierarchy for Z and Long that is also compatible with the `Numeric[Z]` constraint, this goes to `Integral[Z]`. And both `Int` and `BigInt` have evidences showing that they are `Integral` and they both share a supertype with `Long` (`Any`).

Comment: Mortimer, that's interesting; but then why does the last scala snippet compile and run?